# What is ezic gift?

Tags: papers-please

I just got a gift of a thousand credits in the game, which is listed as *EZIC GIFT* in the end of day screen. The ability to uncheck it seems to indicate that something negative will come out of it.

[image: End of day 11 -screen. A strange man brought money. Uncheck to burn it.]

What is it and what are its effects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> EZIC, referred to as the Order of the Ezic Star, is a mysterious
> organization in Papers, Please. The player first encounters EZIC when
> a random immigrant hands a business card over to the player. Seeing as
> the card only appears on the last level of the Beta, EZIC isn't
> mentioned again. However, on the back of the card, an immigrant's name
> is shown. The player must give the card to that person who will then
> say "If you help us, we will help you".
>
> After a few days, The EZIC
> will give you 1000 credits with the option to burn it.

[Source](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/EZIC)

Comment: That said, I can confirm that there *is* an event related to whether or not one accepts the gift later in the game.

Comment: @FEichinger That is what I was more interested in.

Answer (score 14):

### Effects on keeping the money

> If the money is kept, later in the game your neighbors will report you to the government and you will lose the money.

---

### Effects on burning the money

> If the money is burned, they will offer you 2000 the next day. (This money works like the first 1000 and has same choices and effects.) If you burn the money this time as well, the game will continue normally, with no extra consequences.

Comment: If you accept the second bribe, will keeping it lead to the same consequence as accepting the first one?

Comment: @Nolonar I'm not sure. I didn't try it.

Comment: yes, acccepting the second bribe results in the same consequences as the first – [Brian](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/53991/brian) Aug 19 at 23:18

Comment: You don't just lose the money, you lose **all** of your money.  So if you had a large savings at that point, it's better to reject the money.  If you had no savings, you might as well keep it and pay for everything you can while you have it.